# Define a custom type

Tags: go, types, go-gorm

I want to define a new type in GORM like this:

```
type Device struct{
  gorm.Model
  Name string
  Status Status
}
```

Where the values of Status can only be either one of `ok`, `broken`, or `missing`. Obviously, I can use the type string for this, but then I would allow every string possible. How can I restrict the options to the ones I want?

Comment: Did you check the doc for 
Customize Data Types
? https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html

Comment: @Eklavya yes, I checked them. Which section should handle my case? I did not see it.

Comment: If you're using postgres you should create an enum type and use that, I believe you can also specify in a `gorm` tag that the field's related column is of that enum type. As far as Go is concerned, there are no enum types and you can't enforce, at least not *completely*, a field's value, for example even with `Status` declared as the type of the field one can still use an *untyped* constant to assign a value to that field that is not in the set of the declared `Status` constants.

Comment: ... see: https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/1978#issuecomment-476673540

Answer (score 0):

the simplest thing would be something like this:

```
const (
    statusOk      = "ok"
    statusBroken  = "broken"
    statusMissing = "missing"
)

func isValidStatus(s string) error {
    switch s {
    case statusOk, statusBroken, statusMissing:
        return nil
    }
    return errors.New("Invalid status")
}

var d Device
// your code
// your code
// your code

if err := isValidStatus(d.Status); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// valid status
```